# AES/CBC/NoPadding between C# and Java

Tags: c#, java, encryption, aes

I'm using some encryption functions in C# and Java whose output doesn't seem to match. I'm feeding in the same key and IV strings as a test.

Input string: "&app_version=1.0.0.0"

Java:

```
SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));

// Then I convert encrypted to hex by building a string of encrypted[i] & 0xFF
```

Output:

```
60f73a575b647263d75011bb974a90e85201b8dfeec6ec8ffba04c75ab5649b3
```

C#:

```
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider alg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc);

BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;

// Create key and IV buffers
IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(key, encoding);
CryptographicKey cKey = alg.CreateSymmetricKey(keyBuffer);
IBuffer ivBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(iv, encoding);

// Create input text buffer
IBuffer inputBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(input, encoding);
// Do the encryption
IBuffer encryptedBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(cKey, inputBuffer, ivBuffer);

// Convert encrypted back to hex
string encryptedStr = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(encryptedBuffer);
```

Output:

```
4b6fd83c35565fc30a9ce56134c277cbea74d14886cf99e11f4951075d4f4505
```

I am using a Java decrypter to check and it decrypts the Java-encrypted string correctly but the C# string is read as "&app_version=1Q0.0.0" so it seems close but slightly off.

I have checked that the bytes of the key, input, and IV match before the encryption step. Are there any other differences that would cause a discrepancy?

**EDIT** 
With all-zero key "00000000000000000000000000000000" and IV "0000000000000000" I got the same output for both Java and C#:

```
081821ab6599650b4a31e29994cb130203e0d396a1d375c7d1c05af73b44a86f
```

So perhaps there is something wrong with the key or IV that one is reading...

Comment: Could you post the output data for your java code and your C# code?

Comment: Added output and expected value vs actual when decrypted

Comment: AES in CBC mode without padding only works when the input size is a multiple of the block size (16 bytes, 128-bits). Can you verify the data is correctly sized? The behavior of the ciphers may be unexpected if a non-standard input data is offered. And also, try a all-zero IV for the sake of troubleshooting.

Comment: I am padding so that the input is a multiple of 16. I did try 0s for key and IV and got the same output, will add to original question

Comment: Narrowing it down further by setting the key to a "normal" value (keeping the IV all-zero). If it produces different values try again with ECB inside of CBC. I'm not that familiar with C# but the code seems logically sound.

Comment: Key doesn't appear to affect it, the output remains consistent between the two with a normal value.

Comment: Do you specifically need to use SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider, or are you open to using other classes for encryption? Also, do either of your encryption functions (java vs c#) have to stay as they are, or can they be changed?

Comment: I am using SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider for Windows RT, I wasn't sure if there were any alternatives. Looking to stay with AES/CBC/NoPadding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like a fool...my IV contained a zero in one and a capital O in another!! Well, at least I know this code is equivalent.

Comment: LOL! At least you found your problem. By the time you said the keys were fine I was suspecting either a problem with the IV or C#'s AES implementation was broken.